# Make a shell script run *only* while a button is pushed on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to make a device that deauthenticates everything it sees, but only while I'm pressing a button. For this, I'm using a Python script that runs an mdk3 command whenever it detects that GPIO 18 is LOW. I'm not very knowledgeable about Python in general, so I just went around the web trying to find something that fits my use case to no avail. Instead, I attempted to repurpose other code to fit my use case. My code is as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess
import os

FSU = "sudo mdk3 wlan0 d"

# Define a callback function that will be called by the GPIO event system:
def onButton(channel):
    if channel == 16:
        subprocess.run(FSU, capture_output=True, shell=True)



# Setup GPIO16 (can be changed) as an input with internal pull-up resistor to hold it HIGH until it is pulled down to GND by the connected button; this prevents involuntary deauthing
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Register an edge detecting on RISING edge. When this event fires, the callback onButton() will be executed. Because of bouncetime=20, all edges 20 ms after a first rising edge will be ignored
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING, callback=onButton, bouncetime=20)
```

I have a basic understanding of how this works, and (theoretically) this should run a specified script if a button is pushed. However, there are a few problems. Mainly, after running it once, it doesn't constantly monitor GPIO 16; it just runs through it once and exits. Also, even after button release, the mdk3 command is still running. I have somewhat limited knowledge of Python, so it'd be nice if you explained what you did and why you did it. Thanks.

Comment: you may need some loop to keep it running - ie. `while True: sleep(1)`

Comment: @furas is right - add infinite loop to the end of your script. Also you need to use falling edge instead of rising edge. Right now your callback is configured to fire on button release. And please check that your button is shorting the pin to the ground instead of VCC

Comment: Also have a look at https://www.embedded.com/my-favorite-software-debouncers/ . While 20 milliseconds looks like reasonable value based on conclusion of article author I would pick 50 milliseconds or event more to avoid extra spawns of your subproccesses - it is easy to overwhelm your device by single press of button with BAD button which produces noise. I would track rising edge as well to add ```sleep 1 second``` delay in such callback.

Comment: Is this Linux OS? Use *libgpiod* instead of custom broken RPi.GPIO library. Just subscribe to the event of the line change and act accordingly.